# How can we measure the performance of downloading file activity using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Steps:

1. Login into application
2. Dashboard page will be loaded
3. Click on the "User Details" section
4. Select the file and click on the download button.
5. Windows POP-UP will prompt and will ask to SAVE the file.

File will start to download on to specified location

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the file is nothing more than [HTTP GET method](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3), so given your configure [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler URL to point to the file you want to download:

[image: JMeter download file example]

JMeter will download the file when you run the test and measure the associated time.

You can also use [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener if you are interested in the remote file content of plan to reuse the downloaded file later on.

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)